# can I have swiper and counsel as "add-ons" and not the default binding

Tags: isearch, find-file, counsel, swiper

I like the powers that counsel/ivy/swiper gives me, specially
for `C-s` and `C-x C-f`,
but since installing it, I've started missing the vanilla emacs `C-s` and `C-x C-f`.
It would be awesome if I can "call" these enhanced versions if I feel lost.
For example

To look for something I do vanilla Emacs `C-s`, and after a few seconds I realize I need swiper, so I should be able to "hop" in to swiper mode.

Likewise, I do vanilla emacs `C-x C-f`, and after a few tab presses I feel I need counsel(?), so I should be able to to "hop" on to counsel.

Is this a good idea? - Is anybody doing this already? If so how.

Comment: I found a thread that goes halfway to solving my issue here -> https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/89#issue-74385529

Comment: Just bind whatever command (anything) to a key in `isearch-mode-map`.